# Capybara-webkit QtGui requires version 29.0.0 or later

Tags: libpng, dyld, capybara-webkit, qtgui

Hi I'm trying to do some basic messing around with capybara-webkit.
When I try to include the Capybara::DSL I get the following error

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: QtGui requires version 29.0.0 or
>   later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 21.0.0
>   /Users/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@rails3211/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.2/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:95:in
>   `initialize': Can't assign requested address - connect(2)
>   (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Can anyone help?  Confused.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like it was an old edition of imagemagick that was the problem.  Downloading latest version solved it.